# What is the difference between "proportion" and rate"?

Tags: nouns

> The proliferation of electronic bidet seats has increased the
>   proportion/rate of water used in toilets (to the total amount of
>   water used in homes).

I would like to know which of "proportion" and "rate" is suitable for the above sentence I created when the sentence in parentheses is omitted. As far as I could search, I think "rate" is better, but "rate" sometimes means "speed".

Answer (score 1):

*Proportion* is what you're looking for.

*Rate* indicates that **change** is what's being measured, or that you're measuring along two axes. You can measure a rate of acceleration, for example—it's not just measuring speed, or time, but the change in speed over time.

*Proportion* indicates that you are using a measure (volume, in this case) and comparing it to a larger measure that it is a part of. That's precisely what you are measuring here—the volume of the toilet's water relative to the entire house. You're *indicating* that it's changing, but not *measuring* the actual change along both axes.

Comment: Mind you, a __lot__ of people—native speakers—misuse the word _rate._ It's not at all uncommon to see the phrase _rate of speed,_ for example, which would be redundant if it weren't incorrect. (The correct phrase would be _measure of speed,_ which, as I said, would be redundant.) So I'm not surprised that your searches led you to believe that _rate_ would be correct here. A lot of native speakers might use it. But it wouldn't be correct.

Comment: BTW you can edit your answers if you think of new things to add.  You shouldn't need to comment on your own answer, only to respond to other comments.

Comment: I'm aware of that; I did edit my answer. But this was more of an afterthought; not really part of the answer, to my mind. So I was more comfortable adding it as a comment.